# How to perform full text search with modifiers in Elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, nlp, elasticsearch

I am building a web application using Elasticsearch with Playframework[Java] with full text search option. I want to process something like "Sony Ericsson phones **under** 300 dollars" or "Samsung phones **with** 3g". As I am new to Lucene/Elasticsearch, wanted to know what is the best way to go about it.

Do I need to parse terms like "above, below, with" etc in my code and then generate relevant queries for Elasticsearch or there is a better/standard way to do this? I understand that NLP is a very complex area, but wanted to know how others do it and how much of an effort it would be. And I want to add that it doesn't need to be perfect. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Elasticsearch supports slightly modified [Lucene Query Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html) and I am not aware of any plugins that would do what you described. So, you will probably need to do parsing in your application and generate Elasticsearch queries.